# How should CouchDB revisions be treated from a design perspective?

Tags: couchdb, replication, versioning, revision

Near as I can tell, CouchDB revisions are not to be treated like revisions in the **document versioning** sense of the word. From glancing at other posts, they seem to be regarded as transient data that exists until a coarse-grained **compact** operation is called.

My question is, if I am interested in using CouchDB to maintain documents, as well as a version-history of those documents, should I allow that to be handled natively by CouchDB revisions, or should I build a layer on-top that will survive a compact operation?

I am thinking the latter, simply because Couch does not replicate revisions of documents, only the latest update. This makes me think **revision** is a mis-leading name, as it's more of a data structure for stabilizing replication.

Comment: It looks like this may be the answer I was looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717591/is-it-really-wrong-to-version-documents-using-couchdbs-default-behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must build that layer because couchdb revisions are *not* a versioning system for your data.

'revision' is misleading, and so is 'version' and so is every name that has been suggested so far. Suggestions welcome, if only to confirm how tricky naming this is.

Comment: I'm going to throw **variant** in as my suggestion

Comment: Variant seems unspecific. In my software I've used variant to indicate an alternative view of some data. What about something that more reveals the technical side of the dbms, like *write_order* or *save_number*?