# How to fetch older revision of documents, within _revs_limit ,after compaction

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

So I read this on the couchdb wiki page - 
*_revs_limit defines a upper bound of document revisions which CouchDB keeps track of, even after Compaction.*

But when I try to retrieve an older revision (after compaction) which is within the _revs_limit range - I get a 404 Doc Not Found. I am simply doing a GET on docid and old_revid

Can anyone advise on how to keep/fetch say 'n' number of older revisions of a document even after compaction

[·](https://workaround-for-at-least-6-character-edit-limit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, compaction removes all previous revisions, and that cannot be configured. It should also be noted that the revision numbers are not a mechanism of version control, instead it is purely concurrency-control/conflict-prevention.

You'll need to use another method to get document versioning, such as the ones listed in [this blog post](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/652783121/document-versioning-in-couchdb) or [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274762/best-practice-for-couchdb-document-versioning).

Comment: Thanks Dominic .. Yeah, makes more sense now.. revsion thing is kind of a misnomer