# How to prevent couchdb database compacting? Is it a good idea?

Tags: couchdb

I need to store some documents in Couchdb. The document will have one attachment.

Sometimes (rarely) I will need to replace the attachment with a new version, but I need to perserve the old version.

The revision mechanism would be ideal for this task, as it does automagically what I need.

The problem is, CouchDB removes old revisions during compaction.

How to disable _compact operation for one database, so even Admin cannot do it by accident (I know, admin can do anything, and if he would like to, he could re-enable _compact operation and do _compact, but I assume he will not).

Is it even possible? Is it a good idea, or should I write my own revision system, and why?

Best regards

SWilk

EDIT:
It seems the "revision" is not suitable to be a version control system and shold not be used this way: 
[How should CouchDB revisions be treated from a design perspective?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263043/how-should-couchdb-revisions-be-treated-from-a-design-perspective)

Comment: As you found out in [How should CouchDB revisions be treated from a design perspective?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263043/how-should-couchdb-revisions-be-treated-from-a-design-perspective), using the revision mechanism for version control should be avoided. Voting to close.

Comment: Agreed. This isn't the intention, although maybe it should be possible. You'd do better to roll old versions into your documents.